# Как создать словарь по типу X:X*X от 1 до n, используя map()

Tags: python, map, dict, функциональное-программирование

Как создать словарь по типу X:X*X длиной от 1 до n c Map. Должно получиться:

```
{1: 1,
 2: 4,
 3: 9,
 4: 16,
 5: 25,
 6: 36,
 7: 49,
 8: 64,
 9: 81,
 10: 100,
 11: 121,
 12: 144,
 13: 169,
 14: 196,
 15: 225,
 16: 256,
 17: 289,
 18: 324,
 19: 361,
 20: 400}
```

---

```
numbers=[]
for x in range(1,6):
  numbers = map(lambda x: x**2, range(1,10))
print(numbers)
```

Comment: а зачем здесь `map` ?

Comment: @MaxU а я только подумал, что ваш комментарий правильно отвечал на вопрос )

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример того словаря, который вы хотите создать

Comment: такое задание учебное

Comment: @Viktorov, тот кто придумал данное задание выбрал явно не лучший пример для использования функционального стиля ... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [71]: n = 10

In [72]: d = dict(map(lambda x: (x,x**2), range(1, n+1)))

In [73]: d
Out[73]: {1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25, 6: 36, 7: 49, 8: 64, 9: 81, 10: 100}
```

PS но использование `map` в данном случае, по-моему, извращение

---

Если бы не условие использовать `map()` я бы делал это так:

```
In [76]: d = {i:i**2 for i in range(1, n+1)}

In [77]: d
Out[77]: {1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25, 6: 36, 7: 49, 8: 64, 9: 81, 10: 100}
```

выглядит гораздо понятнее...

Comment: Зато в одну строчку

Comment: я так и сделала в предыдущем задании, а потом пошли lambda